Why can't (1,0) be the null vector for the vector space in which (1, x)+(1, y) = (1, x+y)?
I have been trying to see if...
v = { (1,x) ∈ R² }, (1, x) + (1, y) = (1, x+y), k·(1, x) = (1, k·x)
...is a real vector space or not. I can't understand why isn't (1,0) a valid null vector, since it is the neutral element of the sum on this space.

Who told you that it's not a valid null vector??

It is why do you think it isn’t? Also I don’t see why you would define such as space, it is clearly isomorphic to $k$. Here $V = {1} \times k$ it is a copy of $k$

@MishaLavrov one forum and chatGPT. They both said something like: "since it isn't the 'true null vector of R^2' it isn't valid".
I felt it was wrong and that's why I am here

Probably because they misunderstood this with the notion of a subspace. The vector $(1,0)$, with the defined operations, is indeed the null vector, and your set is a real vector space as well.

This is a vector space, and $(1,0)$ is its zero vector.
It is irrelevant that it is not the zero vector of the vector space $\mathbb R^2$. All that says is that your vector space is not "compatible" with $\mathbb R^2$, but we already knew that because the addition and scalar multiplication are defined differently from $\mathbb R^2$.
It is doubly irrelevant what ChatGPT says; it hasn't gotten to the point where it can consistently answer questions correctly.

The set $V = \{(1,x) : x \in \mathbb R\}$ you defined is a vector space with the given operations. It is isomorphic to $\mathbb R$ via $\mathbb R \to V, x \mapsto (1,x)$. And exactly as you suspected, $(1,0) \in V$ is the zero vector. Your argument that $(1,0) + (1,x) = (1,x)$ for all $x$ is completely correct.
What is not true (that's probably where the forum led you astray) is $V$ being a sub-vector space of $\mathbb R^2$. While $V$ is a subset of $\mathbb R^2$ and a vector space on its own, the operations do not match. In $V$, we have $(1,x) + (1,y) = (1,x+y)$, in $\mathbb R^2$ the result is $(2,x+y)$ instead. Probably this confused the forum member who answered you.
Also, do not listen to ChatGPT when it comes to math. It may recite definitions and well known statements and proofs. It does not, however, understand math. It just makes up an answer to your question that sounds like a plausible answer. Whether that answer is correct is a completely different question.

When $V$ is a vector space and we say that $W\subseteq V$ is a subspace of $V$, we mean that $W$ is a vector space on its own right, with the operations restricted from $V$.
So, you're looking at $V=\{(x,y) \in \Bbb R^2 : x=1\}$, with the operations $$(1,x)+(1,y) \doteq (1,x+y)\quad\mbox{and}\quad \lambda\cdot (1,x) \doteq (1,\lambda x).$$Is $V$, with these operations, a vector space? Yes, because you can check that all the axioms in the definition of vector space are satisfied. And the zero vector of $V$, for this vector space structure, is $(1,0)$.
Is $V$, with these operations, a subspace of $\Bbb R^2$ (equipped with its standard vector space structure)? No, because the operations you're considering are not the restrictions to $V$ of the usual operations in $\Bbb R^2$.
